# how to display tool tips on tab menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

In my application I have a tab menu which I created using css.  Whenever  the user moves the cursor on the tab he should be shown a tooltip for that tab.  Is there any solution for this using JQuery or any other concept?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [SimpleTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) plugin might be interesting.

Comment: thanks   for  ur  replay , darin
i have   syntax   issue .
  i have a table   with  i  have 1  tr  inside that .i have  3  td[ which  i have    designed  this as a  tab].    once the  user  moves the cursor  on that   tab(td) i  need  to  provide an  tool   tip. any example  of that  kind  can  solve my issue 

 thank you

Comment: Could you please update your question by posting any relevant source code?